# fs.unlink asyncronous node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise, async.js

When removing async and await the code works normally, what's wrong to get this error if unlink is a async function? And in this case is it really obligatory to have a resolve(...) inside the promise since the unlink only deletes a file function and return null?

```
c:\Users\Flavio\Documents\Coding\projects-my\study-content\study-luiz-miranda\node\file-system\unlink.js:7
  let deletedFile = await fs.unlink(path.join(dir, file));
                    ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:984:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1032:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Flavio\Documents\Coding\projects-my\study-content\study-luiz-miranda\node\app.js:1:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
```

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');

exports.deleteFile = async (dir, file) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
  let deletedFile = await fs.unlink(path.join(dir, file), (err) => {
    if (err) return reject(err);
  });
  resolve(console.log('Deleted'))
})
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to promisify unlink. It already returns a promise because you use fs.promises.

Answer (score 3):

you should better understand the promises

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');

exports.deleteFile = async (dir, file) => { 
    await fs.unlink(path.join(dir, file))      
    console.log('Deleted')
}
```

an async/await function always returns a promise.

Comment: Yes, what you say is fine, but it also depends on what you want to do. I did not want to show a solution, I want him to learn about promises, besides that he should not use the callback. ☺

Comment: Ready, it is already edited. @jfriend00 Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 3):

You're using fs.promises.unlink, which does not take a callback. It instead returns a promise that you can choose to await. You also don't need to use `new Promise()` - `new Promise()` is meant to turn a callback-API into a promised-based one, but you're already working with a promise-based API.

So, this is actually all it takes to do what you're trying to do:

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');

exports.deleteFile = async (dir, file) => {
  await fs.unlink(path.join(dir, file));
  console.log('Deleted')
}
```

To answer your question about weather you're required to use `resolve()` when using `new Promise()`, the answer is *yes*, otherwise your promise will never resolve, and anything waiting for it will await forever. However, you don't have to provide `resolve()` with any specific value if you don't have one to provide.